# Apache and php-fpm doesn't work for script name with forward slashes

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I'm having a problem with one website after moving it to another server. Old one wasn't using php-fpm, new one does, and so far I didn't have any problems related to that when migrating other websites.

The thing with this one is that it uses weird way to achieve symlinks. See what's happening in the .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

index.php explodes PATH_INFO to get needed parameters:

```
$url_elements = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

Home page works fine. What doesn't work is all of the subpages. I get *File not found.* on front, and *AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n'* from php-fpm in the logs.

My idea is that it happens because the php-fpm gets a filename with forward slashes and treats it as a path.

This is the config that Apache uses to process PHP files via php-fpm:

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php7.c>
<IfModule proxy_fcgi_module>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    <IfModule setenvif_module>
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
    </IfModule>

    <FilesMatch ".+\.ph(ar|p|tml)$">
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch ".+\.phps$">
        # Deny access to raw php sources by default
        # To re-enable it's recommended to enable access to the files
        # only in specific virtual host or directory
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
    # Deny access to files without filename (e.g. '.php')
    <FilesMatch "^\.ph(ar|p|ps|tml)$">
        Require all denied
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I can't afford to rewrite code of this website to do friendly URLs in a better way, because this website is just a small page used for SEO purposes and company won't allow to waste time on that right now.

I'd be more than happy if someone would provide me with a simple fix for those errors.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: got your old `.conf` there?

Answer (score 1):

Please try enabling `FollowSymLinks` and `AllowOverride All`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Once done, restart apache2 service with command `sudo systemctl stop apache2` & `sudo systemctl start apache2`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally after investing many hours I found the problem in my case.

It was solved with this php.ini variable:

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

I hope that at least it helps so that another person does not waste so much time.